# How can I have Google Sheets email a row when an email address in entered into that row?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm a total novice at Javascript, but I was able to modify some scripts I found online to get a row emailed to the address in column B of that row. There are three places where I'm totally stuck:

1. How do I trigger the script to run when column B is updated?
2. In line two of my code, I've hard coded the row number as variable dataRow. How do I get the updated row from my spreadsheet?
3. The HTML is rendering in some instances, but not others. The td width in line 22 is not functioning, not is any of the html formatting in lines 46 and 47. I've tried a couple of techniques but nothing is working.

Thank you!

```js
function sendEmails() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var dataRow = 232; //updated row in spreadhseet
 var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 var data = sh.getRange("E:T").getValues();
 var TABLEFORMAT = 'cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" dir="ltr" border="1" style="table-layout:fixed;font-size:10pt;font-family:arial,sans,sans-serif;border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid #ccc;font-weight:normal;color:black;background-color:white;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;font-style:normal;"'
 var htmltable = ['<table ' + TABLEFORMAT +'>'];

 row = 0;

 htmltable += '<tr>';

 for (col = 0 ;col<data[row].length; col++){
   if (data[row][col] === "" || 0) {htmltable += '<td>' + 'None' + '</td>';} 
   else
  if (row === 0)  {
    htmltable += '<th>' + data[row][col] + '</th>';
  }
   else 
  if (col===10){htmltable += '<td>' + data[row][col] + '</td>';}
   else
   {htmltable += '<td width=400px" style="width:400px; background-color:yellow;">' + data[row][col] + '</td>';}
 }

 htmltable += '</tr>';

 row = dataRow - 1;

 htmltable += '<tr>';
 for (col = 0 ;col<16; col++){
   if (data[row][col] === "" || 0) {htmltable += '<td>' + 'None' + '</td>';} 
   else {htmltable += '<td>' + data[row][col] + '</td>';}
 }

 htmltable += '</tr>';

 htmltable += '</table>';


 var dataRange = sheet.getRange(dataRow, 1, 1, 19)
 var data = dataRange.getValues();
 for (i in data) {
  var row = data[i];
  var emailAddress = row[1];
  var ccAddress = row[2];
  var signature = '<span style="font-family:"Arial",sans-serif">Best</span></br>Adam Schwartz </span> </br><span style="font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Arial",sans-serif;color:#48B8DD">  <stong>  MANAGER OF ESCALATIONS - RESIDENTIAL</stong></span></br><span style="font-family:"Arial",sans-serif">SMS ASSIST</span><span style="font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Arial",sans-serif;color:#6C6C6C">  875 N. Michigan Ave. | Suite 2800 | Chicago, IL 60611  </span>';
  var message = "Hello " + row[4] + "," + '</br></br>' +"One of your escalation model tasks was randomly selected for QA last week. Your scores are below, along with my notes." + '</br></br>' + htmltable + '</br></br>' + signature; // Assemble the body text
  var subject = "Preventive Escalation Model QA " + row[19];
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {htmlBody:message,cc:ccAddress});
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi, did your issue get solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need an onEdit trigger in order to fire the function every time column B the spreadsheet is edited. Also, because you want to send emails, a simple trigger won't be enough (see restrictions of simple triggers [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)), you need to install a trigger. You can do this [manually](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) or [programmatically](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically). Here I provide the code to install the edit trigger programmatically. You would have to run this function once:

```js
function createEditTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendEmails')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onEdit()
      .create();
}
```

This will make `sendEmails` run every time the spreadsheet is edited. You would have to put a condition that checks if the edited range is in column B. And you could do that if you use an [Event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit), which will be received by `sendEmails` as a parameter and that contains information about the context that fired the trigger.

Let's say that, as is usual, the event object is called `e`. You can access the range that was edited by doing `e.range`. And you can know the column that was edited if you do `e.range.getColumn()`. Also, you can know which row was updated if you do `e.range.getRow()` (which was your second problem).

With all this said, you would have to modify the function `sendEmails` the following way. You would have to change this:

```js
function sendEmails() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var dataRow = 232; //updated row in spreadhseet
    var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  // Rest of the code
}
```

To this:

```js
function sendEmails(e) {
  var range;
  if (!e) range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange(); 
  else range = e.range; // Edited range
  var sh = range.getSheet(); // Edited sheet
  var dataRow = range.getRow(); // Edited row index
  var column = range.getColumn(); // Edited column index
  var yourSheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please change accordingly
  // Check that edited sheet is the one you want to track change from
  // and that edited column is B (index 2):
  if (sh.getName() == yourSheetName && column == 2) {
    // Rest of the code
  }
}
```

It is very important that you write `e` as an argument for the function, otherwise the code won't know what `e` is. Also please bear in mind that this will only work if the spreadsheet is edited manually by a user, not programmatically by a script).

Also, in this sample, the sheet you want to track changes from is called `Sheet1`, please change it in the code if that's not the case.

Finally, regarding the HTML, I think you are missing some quotes in several places, and that's why it's not working properly. In this line, for example:

```
'<td width=400px" style="width:400px; background-color:yellow;">'
```

The `400px` is missing the first ", it whould be `width="400px"`.

I see a similar thing happening in this line:

```js
'<span style="font-family:"Arial",sans-serif">Best</span> // ...
```

Here, you should be using escape characters (`\"`), otherwise, the script thinks you want to close a quote block when you want to open a new one. You should do something like this:

```js
'<span style="font-family:\"Arial\",sans-serif">Best</span> // ...
```

I hope this is of any help.

Comment: Thanks iamblichus! This is very helpful. I copied and pasted your edits to sendEmails function, but I am getting this error: "TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 10, file "Code")"

Comment: @AdamSchwartz you are welcome. I assume that line 10 refers to `var range = e.range;`. If that's the case, this is most probably happening because you are trying to run the function manually. This is a trigger and it's not supposed to run manually, if you do it, the parameter `e` (which contains information on the context in which the function was called - the edit) is undefined, and that's why you're getting this error.

Comment: @AdamSchwartz I edited my answer so that if you want to run your function manually, the `range` variable is assigned to the [currently active range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactiverange) (for example, the cell that is currently selected in your spreadsheet). This way you won't get an error even if you run it manually.

Comment: Thanks! I was running it manually to test it. I didn't get an email when I expected based on the trigger, so I wanted to see if it worked when I ran it manually. I'm going to troubleshoot the trigger and see if I'm misunderstanding something in there.

Comment: @AdamSchwartz did you install the trigger as I told you? That's necessary in order to send the email.

Comment: @AdamSchwartz I see several problems in your code. For starters, variables `row` and `col` are not defined correctly. For example, you are writing `row = 0` to declare a variable, when it should be `var row = 0`. The same for `for (col = 0 ;col<data[row].length; col++){`, it should be `for (var col = 0 ;col<data[row].length; col++){`. And `sheet` is not declared in the code I provided (because it's the same as `sh`). So it will fail too in here `var dataRange = sheet.getRange(dataRow, 1, 1, 19)`: should be `var dataRange = sh.getRange(dataRow, 1, 1, 19)`.

Comment: @AdamSchwartz those are the problems I saw in a quick review, but there might be more. Please apply these changes to your code and see if that works.

Comment: @AdamSchwartz there is a problem in this line too: `for (i in data) {`. In this case `i` is not declared correctly. And `for... in` is not really recommended iterating through arrays, use this instead: `for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {`

Comment: @AdamSchwartz if you are still having problems after making all the changes I said, please share a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on (free of sensitive information), and I'll try testing this.

Answer (score 0):

I can help with 1 and 2. 3 is an email formatting question and that's normally a pain.

1. There's an `onEdit(e)` function which passes an object to the function. e.g. when I edit cell A7 to contain just the letter a, the object (e) contains this:

   {
     "range": {
       "columnStart": 1,
       "rowStart": 7,
       "rowEnd": 7,
       "columnEnd": 1
     },
     "value": "a"
   }

Within the onEdit function, you could check `(range.columnStart <= 2 && range.columnEnd >= 2)` for changes to column B

2. You may be able to use the row value from the object above. Otherwise, you can find the last row in the sheet using `var lastRow = sh.getLastRow()`